# How to use bootstrap toggle to call a funciton?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, bootstrap-4

I have created a toggle switch using bootstrap. The code for it is as follows:

```
<label >
  Automatic Refresh:
</label>
<input class="pull-right" data-size="mini" type="checkbox" data-
toggle="toggle">
```

In my application, I want to call automatic refresh function when the button is "On" and turn off the automatic refresh when the toggle button is "Off". 
For experimentation purpose, I will be using setInterval() and clearInterval() for toggle On and toggle Off respectively. 
The code which should run when toggle is on is as follows:

```
var int = setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
```

The code which should run when the toggle is set to Off is as follows:

```
clearInterval(int);
```

How do I make a function call on toggle clicks ? 
My toggle button looks like this[image: WhenToggle is On][image: When Toggle is Off]

Answer (score 3):

you can use an `onchange` event.

For this example, I've given your checkbox an id and used that to bind the `onchange` event (there are other options):

```
<input id="data-toggle" class="pull-right" data-size="mini" type="checkbox" data-
toggle="toggle">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('data-toggle').onchange = function(e){

        if(e.target.checked) {
            //Toggle is on
        } else {
            //Toggle is off
        }
};
```

Comment: I will give it a try and will follow-up. Thanks